# Does order matter in this causal language model?

Tags: nlp, machine-learning-model, tokenization

Say you've implemented a causal language model like so:

```
def get_causal_xy(data, max_len=8):
    xs=[]
    ys=[]
    index = 0
    for i in range(len(data) - max_len):
      xs.append(data[index: min(len(data), index + max_len)])
      ys.append(data[index+1: min(len(data), index + max_len + 1)])
      index = index + 1
    return xs, ys
```

would then order matter. Say you have A,B,C,D words and youre trying to find P(y)

would P(y | A, B, C, D) be the same as P(y | C , B , A , D)?

My hunch is yes, because you still have access to the same words, and casual language model like this simple one doesnt use positional encoding

Comment: Probably you mean "causal", not "casual"?

Comment: yes! do you know the answer @MightyCurious